# Conservation of energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics

Consider a weightless vertical rod hinged at its center. Two identical inflated balloons are tied at each end of the rod. Entire system is under influence of gravity and is in air, so there are buoyancy forces on the balloon.(The system is in equilibrium, but is unstable because slightest push will cause the rod to rotate and become horizontal.) Now I heat the bottom balloon by supplying thermal energy equal to Q, and cool the top balloon at the same time by removing thermal energy equal to Q. So bottom balloon expands and the top one contracts. Overall net transfer of energy to this system (rod+balloon) is zero, but the potential energy of the system has increased, because density of air inside the balloon at the top is now greater than that at the bottom, compared to what it was before.

I know energy conservation cannot be violated, so where is the flaw in the argument?

Edit: Say initially, the density of air inside the balloons is the same as that of ambient air, so initially there are no buoyancy forces on the balloon.

Comment: The density of the balloons may change but their masses don't...

Comment: How does density affect energy in this case? Can you explain that?

Comment: @LeLouch You obtain a top-heavy configuration in the latter case.

Comment: @lemon Mass doesn't change but effective gravity acting on the two balloons changes when their densities change (think buoyancy). If it is any help, you may think that initially, density of air in both the balloons was identical to that of atmospheric air and so there are no buoyancy forces on them (equivalently effective gravity on them is zero).

Comment: potential energy of one balloon increases while the other decreases. The relative PE may have increased, but the net PE is zero.

Comment: @Lelouch Net PE of the system (rod+balloon) is not zero because you can convert it into to kinetic energy by slightly tipping the rod and thus causing it to rotate. If initially the air density inside the balloon were identical to that of ambient this would not be possible, so the initial configuration has zero PE.

Comment: Both the initial and final configurations have PE(same) there is no net change in that. in the second case, when we slightly tip over the system, external forces do work, so energy is not conserved. It is not a violation. i hope you see that.

Comment: Are you suggesting that work of tipping over is involved? That is not correct because that work can be reduced to zero in the limit; what is required is only an infinitesimal perturbation, that's all. Kinetic energy that is acquired by the system after it is tipped over does not depend on this tipping work. Consider the case of a body perched on top of a building. It has potential energy because, once you tip it over, it acquires kinetic energy whose magnitude is equal to change in potential energy of the body (ignoring losses).